# DMing The Member Joins The Server - Discord.Py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
channel = client.get_channel(659080736229294130)
await channel.send(f'{member.mention} Katıldı, Hoşgeldin! {channel.guild.member_count} Kişiyiz!')

role = get(member.guild.roles, name=ROLE)
await member.add_roles(role)
print(f"{member} Katıldı!")

if member.guild is None and not member.author.bot:
    async with member.typing():
        await asyncio.sleep(0.7)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Hoşgeldin!",
            colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
        )
        embed.set_thumbnail(
            url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/649985273249398784/493fe440660d331687e426ba976da8f4.webp?size=1024")
        embed.add_field(name="‎",
                        value="**TEXT**",
                        inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="TEXT",
                        value= "TEXT", )
        embed.set_footer(text="© @MakufonSkifto#0432")
        await member.send(embed=embed)
```

The code you see is under

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
```

I want my bot to DM the person who joins the server. I have made a command that welcomes the newcomer thru the welceme channel but I couldn't make DM work. And as the bot didn't know what message is, It makes the text red. When I put `message` on the top It says "message is a required context that is missing" when someone joins. I don't know how to proceed but I definitely need you guys help! I can give the full `on_member_joins` event if you guys want

Comment: No message.channel.send, but: await member.send(embed = embed)

Comment: but what about the other message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send personal messages to a user through `member.send(...)` where `member` is the user in the context (joined the server).

The `<destination>.send(<content>)` function sends the `content`(your message) to the given `destination` which can be a channel, a group or a member(in this case),etc.
Here is a sample code(your code with some changes) which send an embed to the joining user's DM:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print ("{} joined!".format(member.name))
    print (f'{member.guild.name}')
    await member.send("Welcome!")
 
    role = member.guild.roles
    # member.guild.roles returns an object of type <class 'list'>
 
    if member.guild and not member.bot:
        async with member.typing():
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="Hoşgeldin!",
                colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
            )
            embed.set_thumbnail(
                url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/649985273249398784/493fe440660d331687e426ba976da8f4.webp?size=1024")
            embed.add_field(name="something",
                            value="**TEXT**",
                            inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="TEXT",
                            value="TEXT")
            embed.set_footer(text="© @MakufonSkifto#0432")
            await member.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: I changed message with member, but that didn't work out either

Comment: Did you change `message.channel.send(embed=embed)` to `member.send(embed=embed)`?

Comment: Check out the sample code I have added, it should work ;-)

Comment: It's strange because it's working for me. https://pasteboard.co/JePrwW1.png
Can you show the errors?

Comment: Can you put the code which is on the pastebin and edit your answer. I think that might be better

Comment: It's essentially the same except the "roles" thing. I'll add it.
There are some mistakes in your code like `member.guild is None`